# win7 ethernet cord "disconnected" when setting network adapter speed to "auto"

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

When I change the speed&duplex settings of my ethernet adapter to auto, my win7 machiene does not realize I have an ethernet cord connected. Using 10mbit/s full duplex mode works, but my connection is aweful slow. Other people on the same network (university housing) do not experience the same problem.

I tried rebooting (obviously), even loosing power for a while, but to no success.
I tried a different cord, too.
When I used my laptop it worked just fine... (though I'm not sure about what speed setting it used, sadly)
Oh, and the drivers appear to be up to date, I tried updating several times.

Comment: Have you updated your Ethernet adapter drivers? The next step is try a different Ethernet cable and see if this cures the problem. Failing that you may have a physical problem anywhere between your Ethernet adapter itself or the wall outlet (which will require your University halls to investigate).

Comment: Updated the question to include those details

Comment: What happens when you set the speed to 100mbps full duplex? I have a feeling (and have seen this before) that the auto-negotiate is trying to get a 1Gig rate and is causing the problem. This is quite common with older wired buildings or managed networks where the switch ports are set by your provider. I work for a uni and even though we're on gigabit switches with 5e cabling many "auto" cards don't work... hit and miss though. Some work.

Comment: anything above 10mbps full duplex fails

Comment: Contact your halls provider and complain that you're not getting what you're paying for...

Comment: could it be a faulty card, though? the cable is cat5e, as you are using.

Comment: It could be a faulty card. To rule it out try another room connection. If it works fine at higher than 10mbps then it'll be your wall socket...